# Cannot import SongLyrics from lyrics_extractor

Tags: python-3.x

*I wrote this code:*

```py
from lyrics_extractor import SongLyrics

apiKey = 'AIzaSyBDPVEi1OtzB3Nm6i9fd8HTkMCjsselIpM'
engineID = '35df92fbe0cad839c'


extract_lyrics = SongLyrics(apikey, engineID)
lyrics = extract_lyrics.get_lyrics("Reyes de la noche")
print(lyrics)
```

*It is not working, I obtained this import error:*

ImportError: cannot import name 'Songlyrics' from 'lyrics_extractor' (C:\Users\mica\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\lyrics_extractor_*init*_.py)

*What could be wrong?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two problems:

1. You need to install the library with PIP:

   ```sh
   pip install lyrics-extractor
   ```
2. `apiKey` has the wrong capitalization in line 4.

A further suggestion: the returned value is a `dict`, which looks nicer when printed like this:

```py
from lyrics_extractor import SongLyrics

apiKey = 'AIzaSyBDPVEi1OtzB3Nm6i9fd8HTkMCjsselIpM'
engineID = '35df92fbe0cad839c'

extract_lyrics = SongLyrics(apiKey, engineID)
lyrics = extract_lyrics.get_lyrics("Reyes de la noche")
print(lyrics['title'])
print(lyrics['lyrics'])
```

Output:

```
Guasones – Reyes De La Noche Lyrics
Fuimos mucho mas que nada
Fuimos la mentira
Fuimos lo peor
Fuimos los soldados a la madrugada
Con esta ambición
Y ahora estoy en libertad
Y ahora que puedo pensar
En no volver hacer ese
El mismo de antes
Y que tristeza hay en la ciudad, amor
Sábado soleado
Y en el centro de la estatua del dolor
Me sentí parado
Fuimos muchos más que todos
Reyes de la noche
De esta tempestad
Si te vendí, si te robe, te traicione
Fui por uno más
Fuimos perros de la noche
Oxidados en tristeza
Y querer lo que querer
Sin tener que lastimar
Recordando que tu amor
Se robo la dignidad
Ahora olvidemos los dos
No volvamos a empezar
¿Para que?...
```

PS: I was manually writing out lyrics this morning for a song called "Brothers and Sisters" by Les Nubians. When I tried to use this library to get the lyrics for that song, like this:

```
extract_lyrics.get_lyrics("Brothers and Sisters")
```

... I got lyrics for a more popular song of the same title by another musical group. However, after adding the name of the group I wanted, I got the correct song's lyrics:

```
extract_lyrics.get_lyrics("Brothers and Sisters Nubians")
```

Answer (score 0):

Installation

```
pip install lyrics-extractor
```

For more details go to [this](https://pypi.org/project/lyrics-extractor/)